# Why does append print out 'NONE'?

Tags: python

I am trying to add items to a list with the function append. But when I print out the updated list it returns 'None'

Here's what I got so far

```
lists = []
count = 0

while count < 10:
count += 1
ask = input("What note do you want stored?")

lists = lists.append(ask)
print(lists)


>>> What note do you want stored? sd
None
```

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None`, don't assign that back to `lists`.

Comment: Just use  `lists.append(ask)` not `lists = lists.append(ask)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning the result of `lists.append` back to `lists`.  `lists.append` modifies its argument list *and always returns `None`*.  Just do the `lists.append` and don't do anything with its return value.

Instead of

```
lists = lists.append(ask)
```

just do

```
lists.append(ask)
```

The `append` method *modifies the list in place*. It doesn't return the new list; in fact, it doesn't return anything at all, which is why assigning its return value to `lists` gets you a value of `None`.

Comment: Do I need to change the variable name then?

Comment: `append` is modifying the list no need to assign it to `lists`. Just do `lists.append()`

Comment: one more thing when I add to the list and add another item after that it just replaces it